# Analyse input data and find errors in input in big data

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, bigdata, data-analysis

I have a large amount of data( about 20 Gig ) in some text files, and I have all 20 Gig data at once so I don't want to process them partially as they are created, each line in text file specify one record, but this record is in text format and attributes of data are concatenated to each other, this is the sample line in one text file:

```
00000000015tashkhisi---8686745428M.....
```

*First 10 characters show the record number => 0000000001*

*Character at position 11 show type of record => 5*

*Next 12 characters shows owner of the record => tashkhisi---*

*Next 10 characters shows the identity of the owner => 8686745428*

*Next character shows Gender of the owner => M*

and so on ......

This is only an example and you can consider my record has 100 columns or attributes in real data.

But like any other input in big data there are noise in input data and some records are incorrect and have problem, for instance we may have ++--0000001 as record number which is an invalid record number.

Now what I want:
I want to find all errors in my input data and report them in aggregated manner like this:

Record with tashkhisi as owner -> has x% of total Error

Record with Gender M -> has y% of total Error

Error in owner name where record type is 5 => 250000 (y% total)

Error in owner identity when record  type is 5 => 4000000(x% total)

Error in owner name where record type is 3 => 250000 (k% total)

Error in owner identity when record  type is 3 => 4000000( z% total)

......

Total number of name Error => 10000000 with percentage 6%

and so on ....

You can see attributes are interdependent and I need large amount of `group by` and `substring` in my program, Also I want the report to be generated very fast, the size of input data is 20 Gig and I can't load the whole data in memory to work with them.

I know I can use `Spark`, `Elasticsearch` and `logstash`, `mapreduce` and so on. But I want to know which one is better in doing this specific task and why? I want to know what is the best approach to generate this report, Is there any tool to generate this report very fast? Please give me your reason why you suggest that tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use spark to read the data as a dataframe and once the dataframe is ready yoou can perform the valid and invalid checks over that to generate the required statistics.

Now the tricky part is to generate the dataframe, to do so you can do the following.

```
df = spark.read.text(r"C:\stackoverflow\samples\fixedWidth.txt")

df.select(
    df.value.substr(1,10).alias('RecordNumber'),
    df.value.substr(11,1).alias('Type'),
    df.value.substr(12,12).alias('Owner'),
    df.value.substr(24,10).alias('identity'),
    df.value.substr(34,1).alias('gender')
).show()

+------------+----+------------+----------+------+
|RecordNumber|Type|       Owner|  identity|gender|
+------------+----+------------+----------+------+
|  0000000001|   5|tashkhisi---|8686745428|     M|
|  ++--000001|   5|tashkhisi---|8686745428|     M|
|  _+00000001|   5|tashkhisi---|++86745428|     M|
|  0000000001|   5|tashkhisi---|8686745428|     M|
|  0000000001|   5|tashkhisi---|8686745428|     M|
|  0000000001|   5|tashkhisi---|8686745428|     M|
|  0000000001|   5|tashkhisi---|8686745428|     M|
+------------+----+------------+----------+------+
```

Now from this dataframe, there are multiple opportunities, you can directly generate the stats over this using spark only or if you have an active ES cluster then load into ES(not recommended though)

ES is good if your data is json structured and you want a fast search feature over your dataset. For aggregations and all ES provides approximate results.